# Can I use slider for font size plugin in TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMCE plugin. Currently, my font-size option comes with list dropdown but I want slider for font size.

Is this possible with the TinyMCE. Anyone know how can I achieve this with TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE does not have a built in way to select font size via a "slider".  As TinyMCE is open source you can always modify the editor's code to meet your needs.

If you look in the main `tinymce.js` file you will find code like this:

```
editor.addButton('fontsizeselect', function() {
        var items = [], defaultFontsizeFormats = '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt';
        var fontsize_formats = editor.settings.fontsize_formats || defaultFontsizeFormats;

        each(fontsize_formats.split(' '), function(item) {
            var text = item, value = item;
            // Allow text=value font sizes.
            var values = item.split('=');
            if (values.length > 1) {
                text = values[0];
                value = values[1];
            }
            items.push({text: text, value: value});
        });

        return {
            type: 'listbox',
            text: 'Font Sizes',
            tooltip: 'Font Sizes',
            values: items,
            fixedWidth: true,
            onPostRender: createListBoxChangeHandler(items, 'fontsize'),
            onclick: function(e) {
                if (e.control.settings.value) {
                    editor.execCommand('FontSize', false, e.control.settings.value);
                }
            }
        };
});
```

This is how the current select list is implemented - you can always replace this with logic to implement font selection in a different manner.